# "Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers" v/s "Eclipse SDK" install package

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I recently inherited Eclipse Plug-In development project from my co-worker. I have done lots of Java programming, but this is my first time for Eclipse Plug-In development.

I have few questions regarding `Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers` v/s `Eclipse SDK` install packages. My co-worker has been using `Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers` to develop the plugin. But while researching I found `Eclipse SDK` install package. https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#installation suggests installing `Eclipse SDK` for plugin development.

1. What's the difference between `Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers` and `Eclipse SDK` installation packages? I understand in broad sense what an IDE and SDK is. But, if my co-worker was using `Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers` for plugin development then what would I benefit/loose if I use `Eclipse SDK`? What are use cases for `Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers` and `Eclipse SDK`?
2. For version 4.23 (2022-03), the windows download of `Eclipse SDK` is 251 MB (https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.23-202203080310/), whereas download of `Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers` is 425 MB (https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-03/r). What does the `Eclipse IDE for RCP and RAP Developers` installation package provides that `Eclipse SDK` installation package does not?

I am at a loss. I have not been able to find answers to these...

Comment: This is too broad to answer in detail. The Eclipse SDK is the absolute minimum code to do Eclipse plugin/RCP development. Eclipse IDE for RCP/RAP includes the SDK plus numerous additional helpful plugins (GIT, Maven, ...) and support for RAP.

Comment: @greg-449: That clarifies a whole lot more for me. Thanks.

Comment: The [Eclipse Packaging Project](https://eclipse.org/epp) builds the Eclipse IDE packages from artifacts developed by different Eclipse projects (each with there own team, repositories, etc.), e.g. Git support by JGit and EGit, Maven by m2e, etc. One of the Eclipse projects is the [Eclipse project](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/) with its sup-projects Platform and JDT and the Eclipse project is the project that provides the Eclipse SDK.

Comment: @greg-449: I suppose, my confusion was because I, wrongfully, assumed that `Eclipse SDK` contained everything + the source code, Kind of like a superset of Eclipse IDE installs.